# SQL Query - How to filter based off of many similar traits

Tags: postgresql

Would anyone know what the SQL query would look like for the following scenario?

My first table is composed of list of users such as:
**Table 1 Name: Users**

```
[
{id: 1, name: Bob},
{id:2, name: Sam},
{id:3, name: John}
]
```

My second table is composed of list of hobbies such as:
**Table 2 Name: Hobbies**

```
[
{id:1, hobby: Soccer},
{id:2, hobby: Cooking},
{id3, hobby: Reading}
]
```

Since a user can have many hobbies, i have a relational table to link the 2 tables above.
For example, if user 1 Bob has soccer and cooking as hobby, user 2 Sam has reading as hobby, and user 3 John had cooking for hobby, the table would look like:
**Table 3 Name: UsersHobby**

```
[
{id:1, user_id:1, hobby_id:1},
{id:2, user_id:1, hobby_id:2},
{id:3, user_id:2,hobby_id:3},
{id:4, user_id:3, hobby_id:2}
]
```

My question is, how would i go on about filtering as a specific user and see which other users in the database shares 1 or more similar hobby as me.
For example, as Bob i want a table that returns [3] because user_id 3 who is John shares a same hobby as me which is cooking. User id 2 who is Sam would not show up because his hobby is reading, and Bob does not have reading as his hobby.
However, if db got updated and there was a 4th user who had soccer as hobby. Then the return would be [3,4]. (User 3 is inserted because they share hobby id 2 and user 4 is inserted because they share hobby id 1)

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you for taking the time to read this!

I am able to filter if i had an array of hobby that a specific user has and iterate through each hobby 1 by 1 to filter who has the same hobby as me. However, i was wondering if there was an easier and more effective way to do so.
For example, for Bob above, his hobby array would look like [1,2].
Then iterating through the array, filter the SQL to find user whos hobby_id is also 1 and/or 2.

Comment: Sample data is better presented in a table like format (the way your SQL client displays it). Showing a JSON result can easily be mistaken as a question to return a JSON formatted result or even worse, that the data is stored in a single JSON column rather than rows and columns. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this ?

```sql
select id, name from Users 
where id in (
  select user_id from UsersHobby 
  where hobby_id in (
    select hobby_id from UsersHobby where user_id in 
    (select id from Users where name = 'Bob')
  )
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thank you so much and really appreciate the response!